# Dojox chart number of Y axis labels

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

When I create a DojoX vertical bar chart, it automatically calculates the labels on the Y axis to cover the largest value. In this case, it created 3 Y-axis labels, 100, 200 300.

How do I increase the number of labels, to say intervals of 50 rather than intervals of 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an axis, there are several options you can use for the tick marks. Example:

```
chart.addAxis("y", { 
    majorTicks    : true, // default
    majorLabels   : true, // default 
    majorTick     : {length: 4, color: "#FFF"},
    majorTickStep : 10, 
    minorTicks    : true,
    minorLabels   : true,
    minorTick     : { length: 2, color: "#CCC"},
    minorTickStep : 5,
    ...
    vertical: true
 });
```

Check the API docs for more: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/charting/axis2d/Default